# How to change integer to string with go in this case?

Tags: go, go-gorm

Using `gorm` to connect db. Here get all the records:

```
  func GetPeople(c *gin.Context) {
         var people []Person
         var count int

         find_people := db.Find(&people)
         find_people.Count(&count)
         if err := find_people.Error; err != nil {
                 c.AbortWithStatus(404)
                 fmt.Println(err)
         } else {
                 c.Header("X-Total-Count", &count)
                 c.JSON(200, people)
         }
  }
```

About `count`, the `c.Header("X-Total-Count", &count)` can't passed since this error:

```
cannot use &count (type *int) as type string in argument to c.Header
```

Have tried `strconv.Itoa(&count)`, got another error:

```
cannot use &count (type *int) as type int in argument to strconv.Itoa
```

So how to convert integer to string in this case?

Comment: What do you do with count variable in this case? You mean count is the counter of people records, isn't it?

Comment: @ThanhHH Yes. I have updated the question. Sorry for one line mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `c.Header()` call pass the value of the variable instead of a pointer.

```
c.Header("X-Total-Count", strconv.Itoa(count))
```

For reference, [the method signature](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/caf3e350a548af1add9def68087ac53d1d000caa/context.go#L612) is:

```
func (c *Context) Header(key, value string) {
```

Comment: Can also use `fmt.Sprintf("%v", count)` but I believe the above is faster.